# why is a pre-flight request occurring?

Tags: cors

My chrome extension works fine sometimes if I have another of my applications open (which doesn't use CORS). But sometimes the browser extension sends a pre-flight request and then my code doesn't work.

Here is the request header in the case when a preflight is unfortunately sent:

```
OPTIONS /sub_crud/Subit_backend/register HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xxxxubstantiation.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: chrome-extension://xxxxlhfmhghjhbkkkaaammfocdpib
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

The error I get is:

> "has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field
>   x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response."

But I don't want to send a preflight and don't know why a preflight is sometimes being sent. I am wondering if the problem has something to do with Preflighted requests and redirects? also, here is the code that sets up the request:

```
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
//  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'text/plain');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With",'xmlhttprequest');
//  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
```

I tried using text/plain as the content-type but that didn't work. I also commented out the access-control-allow-origin, but that didn't work.

Any ideas on how to stop the pre-flight? or if I can't stop the preflight, how to set up Apache to respond to it?

Additional Information*******************
1) both the browser js code and the server code (CI) are mine. 
2) I really didn't even want a preflight request. Because I am sending type=application/json, the browser decided to make it OPTION. 
3) My PHP function is not getting fired. I have a debugger on it too. 
4) I modified the httpd.conf on the server to get include:

> ```
>   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
>   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept,Authorization,Content-Type,Origin"
>   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE"
>   Header set Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
> ```
>
> 5) the code, both the browser extension and the server have worked in the past.

Comment: Using non-[CORS-safelisted request headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header) causes a preflight request, and a Content-Type of `application/json` does as well. // Your server has to answer this OPTIONS request with an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header, that _allows_ the real request to be made using that `x-requested-with` header.

Comment: thanks misorude. I commented out all the headers except the content-type as text/plain and this seemed to get rid of the preflight. But how to get json response?

Comment: _“But how to get json response?”_ - by making your server-side script _respond_ with JSON …? The `Content-type` _request_ header specifies the format of the data you are _sending_, not what you will get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In CORS, a preflight request with the OPTIONS method is sent, so that the server can respond whether it is acceptable to send the request with these parameters.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) link for more details about `options` http method.

So the issue is your server has not allowed CORS for header `x-requested-with`.

```js
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With",'xmlhttprequest'); // here is the issue
```

Now either you can comment this line or if it is required then allow this header in your server.

For setting in server you can use `.htaccess` file

Comment: Thanks hvish. I'm on bitnami setup and they have renamed .htaccess so I need them to tell me where to allow for a prfilght response.